# DoAuthorzie in PayPal without a signature?

Tags: php, paypal

I am implementing a paypal API  (express checkout) for our clients to be able to pay each other back and forth and get authorized before being charged (Authorize and Capture)  but we do not want them to have to get a signature from paypal. is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. It's not possible. Are you sure PayPal (Adaptive) preapproved payments isn't a better solution for what you're trying to do?

Comment: i looked into it a little bit, i guess I will have to look a little more into the preapproval payment process. We are using apadptive payments for mass pay right now. may be easier. Thanks!